# MS Access Pass-Through Query With "Returns Records: No" Truncates ODBC Connect Str

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, stored-procedures, odbc

This is a very strange one and I can't seem to find anyone else on the web who's experienced it, but I'm attempting to run an SQL Server UPDATE stored procedure (returns 0 records) via an MS Access 2010 pass-through query, but when I set `Returns Records: No` it appears to truncate my ODBC Connect String and throws an error!

(sanitised strings in parens, no parens used in actual string)

ODBC Connect Str:
    `ODBC;DSN=(dsn name);Description=(description);Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=(example database name)`

First, setting `Returns Records: Yes` allows the query to execute successfully (confirmed through SQLServer Mgt Studio) but throws error: `Pass-through query with ReturnsRecords property set to True did not return any records.`

Then setting `Returns Records: No` throws error `The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query 'ODBC;DSN=(dsn name);Description=(description);Trusted_Connection=Yes;DA'. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly.`

Because it probably matters, my DSN is 8 chars long, Description is 8 chars, and Database is 21 chars. I don't think they're excessively long, and the DB is in production and used by several clients, so changing / shortening them at this point is infeasible.

Has anyone else experienced this or can anyone else reproduce?

I've heard that MS Access has a built in hard limit of 255 chars for the ODBC connect str, but mine is certainly <100!

Comment: How are you calling the pass-through query?

Comment: When you open the query (with "Returns Records: No") in design view, put the correct ODBC string back in and save, is it truncated again?

Comment: Please see my comment to Albert below describing how I call the query. After executing the query connection string is still the original version I wrote, it appears that pasting the same string back in 'over the top' makes no difference!

Answer (score 1):

I have a saved query called `qryPass`. It is set to return records = no.

To use the above, in code we can go:

```
With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryPass")
  .SQL = "Exec myStoreProc"
  .Execute
End With
```

In above I of course provide the pass-though sql, but if you not needing to provide the SQL/t-SQL on the fly then you can run the above saved pass-though like this:

```
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryPass").Execute
```

Since you not provided the 2-3 lines of code as to how you call this stored procedure, then we can only guess as to your issues. However try the above approach.

Also before running the query in code, use 100% the UI, create the PT query and try running it (with returns records = no).

Comment: Let's say one of my stored procedures is called `qryExampleStoredProcedure` in the SQL Server instance.

In MS Access I have created a pass-through query (called, for example `qryMSAccessPassThrough`) that contains only `exec dbo.qryExampleStoredProcedure`, within the query properties I have the ODBC connection string as in my question above, and `Returns Records: No`.

I call this query from within VBA using `DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryMSAccessPassThrough"`

This is when the error message is encountered.

Your code appears to make no difference to this!

Comment: error message suggests that the sproc is returning records (or something) Try creating the PT query, and inside have exec dbo.qryExampleStoedProcedure. Now close the query and double click on it to run it. (and try with returns records = yes, and with returns reocrds = no). So built + try the PT query from Access (not from SSMS). I do see a error occur when the sproc returns records, but the query set return records = no.